# IEnumerable implementation breaks on foreach

Tags: c#, linq, foreach, enumeration

I'm using the PDFNet library to extract objects from a PDF and then OCR. I instantiate my `Elements` object:

```
public class Processor
{
    public static int Main(string[] args)
    {
       Elements pdfPageElements = new Elements(pdfPage);
       ...
```

---

The constructor (in a separate class) looks like

```
internal class Elements : IEnumerator<Element>, IEnumerable<Element>
{
    private readonly int _position;
    private readonly ElementReader _pdfElements;
    private Element _current;

    public Elements(Page currentPage)
    {
        _pdfElements = new ElementReader();
        _pdfElements.Begin(currentPage);
        _position = 0;
    }

    ...
```

---

After instantiating `pdfPageElements` I go back to Main() and use Linq to iterate through the collection items to get the PDF objects (in this case images) that I want.

```
var pdfPageImages = (from e in pdfPageElements
                     where
                         (e.GetType() == Element.Type.e_inline_image ||
                          e.GetType() == Element.Type.e_image)
                     select e);
```

---

The PDFNet SDK implements the MoveNext() Method as follows:

```
public bool MoveNext()
{
   if ((_current = _pdfElements.Next()) != null)
    {
        return true;
    }
    else
    {
        _pdfElements.Dispose();
         return false;
     }
 }
```

---

`pdfPageImages` is instatiatied nicely; `Console.WriteLine(pdfPageImages.Count());` returns the right number of images for my test PDF.

But when I send `pdfPageImages` through a `foreach loop` I get the following exception:

```
pdftron.Common.PDFNetException: Unknown exception.
 at pdftron.PDF.ElementReader.Next()
 at pdftron.Elements.MoveNext()
 at System.Linq.Enumerable.WhereEnumerableIterator`1.MoveNext()
 at DM_PDFProcessor.Processor.Main(String[] args)
```

---

It's probably worthwhile to note that int he PDFNet Documentation it states that:

```
Every call to ElementReader::Next() destroys the current Element. 
Therefore, an Element becomes invalid after subsequent 
ElementReader::Next() operation.
```

However, once the element is read into the IEnumerable pdfPageImages, it should be iterable indefinitely (from my limited understanding).

---

Note that the elements in the collection are *definitely* **not null**. Any ideas why I keep getting the exception?

Comment: The fact that it implements `IEnumerable<T>` *and* `IEnumerator<T>` is almost always a bad sign, unless it's been implemented using an iterator block (in which case the compiler will do the right thing). It sounds like the `Element` class is broken by design.

Comment: If the `Count()` method iterates over the collection (which it will do if there's no `Count` property or something similar), then the `ElementReader::Next` method destroy each element after it's been visited. So the next time you try to iterate over the collection, the elements are no longer valid.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Note that

```
var pdfPageImages = (from e in pdfPageElements
                     where
                         (e.GetType() == Element.Type.e_inline_image ||
                          e.GetType() == Element.Type.e_image)
                     select e);
```

is lazily evaluated. That is, every time `pdfPageImages` is enumerated, `pdfPageElements` is also enumerated. So if the `Elements` class is built so that an instance can only be enumerated once without throwing, you might want to cache the query result:

```
var pdfPageImages = (from e in pdfPageElements
                     where
                         (e.GetType() == Element.Type.e_inline_image ||
                          e.GetType() == Element.Type.e_image)
                     select e).ToList();
```